# Fragment layout inflate optimization

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I'm creating an app which has only one `Activity`, a `FragmentActivity` who works like a *"`ViewPager` dashboard"* with some option pages (`ViewPager Fragments`) and for each page I've some options buttons.
 This option buttons toggle a ***SlideUp Menu (SM)*** that changes its layout (submenu `fragment`) according with the button pressed. 

This submenus are created inside their parent `fragment` menu method (which calls createFragments()):

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

The parent menu has 3 helper methods to manage it submenu `fragments`:

```
private void createFragments() {
    ...
    mSubMenuFragmentMap.put(..., new SubMenuFragment(...)); 
    for (Map.Entry<String, BaseSubMenuFragment> frag : mSubMenuFragmentMap.entrySet()) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mMenuSlideUp.getId(), frag.getValue(), frag.getKey()).commit();
    }
    hideFragments();
}


private void hideFragments() {
    for (Fragment frag : mSubMenuFragmentMap.values()) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag).commit();
    }
}

private void changeSubMenuFragment(int elementResId) {
    if (!isVisible) {
        mCurrentSubMenuFragment = mSubMenuFragmentMap.get(Integer.toString(elementResId));

        hideFragments();
        if (mCurrentSubMenuFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mCurrentSubMenuFragment).commit();
        }
    }
    toggleSlideMenu();
}
```

The `changeSubMenuFragment` it's called by the options buttons inside the `ViewPager` menu page.
The `SubMenuFragment extends BaseSubMenuFragment` that has 2 abstract methods:

```
protected void onLayoutSetup(ViewGroup rootView)
```

and

```
protected void onLayoutRefresh(boolean slideMenuIsUp)
```

The `onLayoutSetup` it's called when the submenu slides up for the first time, the `onLayoutRefresh` it's called every time the submenu is toggled (slide up or down).

Everything works as expected but I'm experiencing a little delay when the submenu's layout it's created and displayed (`onLayoutSetup`), but only for the first time. This delay it's bigger if my submenu has `ListViews` (when setting the `BaseAdapter`) or `ScrollViews`. What happen is the submenu slides up, I wait for about 2 seconds (it's an example because it  depends on the submenu layout complexity) and the layout shows up (this submenu from now on will not experience delays when showing).
What I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks for your time